How to access https proxy dev server on WSL in windows web browser?
WSL2.
Ubuntu-22.04 LTS
Next.js
Run dev with mkcert and local-ssl-proxy, so dev server run on wsl via https proxy with custom domain.
But, I can't access that server in Windows web browser.
Only accessible in Ubuntu internal web browser.
I tried some solutions maybe? ex)windows network setting(port forwarding)
But nothing work...
Is there any way to get that?
I changed

Windows Network Inbound rule(add 3000 port allow)
Add my custom domain name to windows hosts.
And other things....I can't remember everything...

